# What is the best way to provide plugin users with a way to customized the styles

Tags: plugin-development, themes, css, configuration

I'm working on a plugin to be release to the public, it is a very simple plugin that includes a single html element in the page html. 
I can do many things to allow users customize its appearance:
1. Let them override a default CSS that is includes as a plugin configuration (on a management screen) 
2. Require that they modify their styles.css (not a very good idea for this plugin) 
And probably a fee more

option 1 seems like the most user Friendly, since it allows any admin to modify the style without need of accessing code. But I wonder if there might be a better way?

Is it possible to provide a default CSS file for the plugin that would be theme independent and would be editable through a management screen? The styling needs to persist regardless of chosen theme.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes.

## Option 1

Simply register and enqueue your default stylesheet.  The theme stylesheet can then be used to override whatever styles you implemented.

```
function register_my_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'default-style', plugins_url('default.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'default-style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_styles' );
```

## Option 2

Register whatever custom options you need either on a specific plugin options page or using the [WordPress Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).  Then output these styles in a regular old script block in the theme header.

```
function output_custom_scripts() {
    ?><style type="text/css">
        <?php echo get_option( 'custom_css' ); ?>
    </style><?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'output_custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you for a well explained and detailed answer. Truth is I still don't understand how the CSS overriding works... how does the browser "know" which of the styles to choose when two identical styles exist, in fact I have seen cases when it did this wrongly - so that I had to make my overriding style's selector a lot more specific.

Comment: CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet.  The browser uses either the most specific rule (i.e. it will use `div#header p.text` over `div#header p`) or the *last* rule specified (i.e if there are two `div#header` rules, it will use the last one it sees).